# Select img within multiple div on div MouseOver

Tags: jquery

I have many `<div>` tags separate from each other. They all have this layout:

```
<div class="swatchimgouter">
    <div class="swatchimginner">
        <img src="myimage.jpg" alt="Green"/>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="swatchimgouter">
    <div class="swatchimginner">
        <img src="myimage.jpg" alt="Black"/>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="swatchimgouter">
    <div class="swatchimginner">
        <img src="myimage.jpg" alt="Red"/>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="swatchimgouter">
    <div class="swatchimginner">
        <img src="myimage.jpg" alt="White"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Am wanting to get the `"alt"` attribute of the `<img>` when the `swatchimgouter` div is hovered. This event fires fine when hovered:

```
$("#variations div.swatchimgouter").mouseover(function () {

}
```

I've tried many combinations of selectors, but none of them are giving me access to the `<img>` attributes. Since there are many of these `div` tags with a class of swatchimgouter, and the one I want is the one that triggers the above mouseover event, do I use `this` somehow to get to the img? Something like:

```
var previewColor = $('div.swatchimginner img', this).attr('alt');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im not to sure what you have tried but your example is more or less working for me:

```
$("#variations div.swatchimgouter").mouseover(function () {
    var previewColor = $('img', this).attr('alt');
    alert(previewColor);
});
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JtQfh/

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/KKz2k/3/)**

```
$("#variations div.swatchimgouter").mouseover(function () {

    var previewColor = $('img', this).attr('alt');    

});
```

Comment: There are many img tags. Each one is wrapped in `<div class="swatchimgouter">` and `<div class="swatchimginner">` wrappers. The example you provided isn't working either - though I hadn't tried accessing the img with the inner div yet.

Comment: I wasn't familiar with jsfiddle. Thanks for that reference, I'll make use of it! I edited my question. Added more instances of these div tags. I don't think `div.swatchimginner` will select the img I'm needing. I need the one that is wrapped by the div that triggered the mouseover.

Comment: No, just want the img inside the div that is hovered. My example actually works... I don't know why it wasn't working for me before, but it works now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
var myAlt = $('img').attr("alt");
```

or if you have lots of imags everythwere:

```
var myAlt = $('div.swatchimginner img').attr("alt");
```

The quickest method is supplying an id for your img element, and selecting by that.

Comment: These `<div><div><img></div></div>` are created in a loop. The inner and outer divs all have the same classes. I'm thinking the only way I can distinguish which img I am interested in is by using `this` as a reference. It should be pointing to the correct div upon entering the mouseover event? All 3 of you provided basically the same example code. But this doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#h').mouseover(function() { 
        var s = $('#in img').attr('alt');
        alert(s);
    });
    });
```